# Python - Issue in Installing Argpath for python 2.6.6 version

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, fedora, python-2.6

I have had installed argpath package for python2.6.6 in my system. But when i try to run my script which requires argparser module, still throwing error "ImportError: No module named argparse"

i am using Fedora 20, so the default version is Python 2.7. So i have installed python 2.6 in some other path ( alias python='/usr/local/bin/python2.6' ) and i have installed argparser using pip tool as shown below and it said "Successfully installed"

```
[root@127 python2.6]# pip install --target=/usr/bin/Python2.6/lib/python2.6/ argparse
Downloading/unpacking argparse
  Downloading argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz (69kB): 69kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package argparse

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rej' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
Installing collected packages: argparse
  Running setup.py install for argparse

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rej' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
Successfully installed 

argparse
Cleaning up...
```

But when i try to run my python script, it is still saying the same error as below

```
[root@127 python2.6]# python /home/rajamm/python_scripts/json2csv.py -f /home/rajamm/python_scripts/cvl.json -o /home/rajamm/python_scripts/cvl.csv
Exception in user code:
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rajamm/python_scripts/json2csv.py", line 6, in <module>
    import fileinput, argparse, json, csv
ImportError: No module named argparse
------------------------------------------------------------
Exiting1.
```

I have stuck for 2 days with this issue. Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got resolved myself. Actually it was my mistake with the wrong path,

Installed path for argparser:

```
[root@127 python2.6]# pwd
/usr/local/lib/python2.6
[root@127 python2.6]# 
[root@127 python2.6]#
```

But Mistakenly installed in the below path:

```
[root@127 python2.6]# cd /usr/local/bin/ (Wrong one)
[root@127 bin]# ls -ltr | grep arg
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   87791 Sep 22 17:40 argparse.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   61546 Sep 22 17:56 argparse.pyc
```

Actually i am a corporate user and i had a proxy issue. So i have resolved by using the below command for the proxy issue.

`pip install -U argparser` - It will not work if you have proxy setting in your network.

So i have tried below one for the Proxy issue,

`export https_proxy=<username>:<password>@<proxy url>:<port no>`  - If your password has special chars, then you need to handle it accordingly.

So the pip installer installed argparser in the default Python2.7 location.

Then i have modified the command like below,

```
pip install --target=/usr/bin/Python2.6/lib/python2.6/ argparse
```

Finally it will install the argparser package in the specified directory. But here also i made a mistake in the path..

For me, i have specified `/usr/local/lib/python2.6` to get it resolved.

So the final commands are :

```
1. export https_proxy=<username>:<password>@<proxy url>:<port no>
2. pip install --target=/usr/local/lib/python2.6/ argparse
```

Now it is working fine.. Thank God.